# Vim syntax highlighting "hi def link" changes colors for certain mappings

Tags: vim, colors

I have a vim syntax color file with lines like:

```
hi Function guifg=#536991 guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=60 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold           
hi def link Define         Function                                                                                                                                    
hi def link TypeDef        Function
```

OK, those all work perfectly fine. But if I want to do:

```
hi Type guifg=#008787 guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=30 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
hi def link Identifier     Type
```

Or:

```
hi Keyword guifg=#BD9800 guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=136 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
hi def link Statement      Keyword
```

Suddenly vim thinks I'm crazy for wanting to link these colors and it *changes* them slightly. For instance, the Type color is usually a teal color, but Identifier is a light blue when linked to Type. The Keyword color is deep yellow, but Statement becomes light yellow when linked to Keyword. I don't have anything else defining "Identifier" or "Statement" colors in the file. If I specifically define the colors for each token (which is a lot of repetition), this doesn't happen. Is vim trying to tell me that I'm stupid for wanting to link these colors, am I misunderstanding the function of highlight linking, am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug (which I doubt)?

If vim is purposely changing these, is there a way to make it stop?

Comment: As with almost any other setting in Vim, use the `:verbose` command prefix to see what script last changed the setting. E.g. `:verbose hi Identifier` should tell you what script last set highlighting for the Identifier type. Linking highlight groups should always *just work* even if they are "special" names; and IIUC "Identifier", "Statement" etc. are only special by convention.

Comment: Hmm, verbose tells me "Type" was last set in my color.vim file, but tells me "Identifier" was last set in (presumably) the default file: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim. This is true for any links I try to create between "default" colors, for instance linking Comment to Type, or Function to Type. They all become a different color than the one I'm linking, but "Type" is always correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `hi`, you can use `hi!` to allow links to override any defaults.

```
hi Type guifg=#008787 guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=30 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
hi! link Identifier     Type
```

After extensive testing and research, it appears as if basic default syntax highlighting groups will always have highlighting defined. For instance, Comments, Functions, etc. *always* have highlighting defined; doing `hi clear` simply sets them back to defaults. You *cannot* link a group if the group already has highlighting unless you use the `!` flag to `highlight`. This is why it worked for TypeDef but not Identifier: Identifier has a default color defined; TypeDef does not.

Comment: You certainly can link default colors to other default colors! Something else is going on.

Comment: I edited my answer; a combination of your `verbose` suggestion and further research led me to the proper answer. Thank you!

Comment: Much better! Note also that `hi def` will do nothing if a link or a rule is defined already, so your command was doing nothing for that reason as well. But you're right, I think you need the `!` here.